# Checkbox array in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have these checkboxes on my website and user choices the appropriate one for himself. What is the best way to store it in the database? For example, user selects "Bluetooth", "Camera", "Sunroof" and "Taxi". And I insert their value as an array to the database like "2 3 7 15". How can I later echo them and make them to shows on the page like "Bluetooth Camera Sunroof Taxi"? Or do you have any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

P.s: As my website will be multilanguage, for this reason, I cannot store just string values.

[image]

Comment: Add all these options to a database table called "options", where each option is a record with an option ID. Use a pivot table to add records for users who have specific options, where each pivot table record represents that the user has selected an option.

Comment: who says that if you store them as string in the database you will break the multi-language ?? you can store it as string `language_key` and use this key in the language array `$lang['language_key'] = 'The actual message to be shown';` !

Comment: Too many checkboxes. I recommend using **multiselect dropdown** instead

Comment: @Maraboc it means if I write value="<?php echo lang("language_key"); ?>" it will insert the word itself,not the code, yes?

Comment: Yes, but before that you have the load the language you want use !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of store you can make a string of id's by using implode like,

```
$checkboxes = $this->input->post('check[]');
$check_array = implode(',',$checkboxes);
```

it makes a string of id's for you like 1,2,3 and so on...
and store it in one column.

then at the time of retrieval
you can explode that and make an array

```
explode(',',$check_array);
```

for display you can match the values with this array and if match found put it selected.
I hope it helps. thank you.

Comment: it means for every checkbox I should write an if statement, yes?

Comment: nop i think you can make a foreach for this array `explode(',',$check_array);` and check with every value and if match found make it selected.

Comment: <?php foreach(explode(',',$check_array) as $selected){ ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="bluetooth" value="1" <?php echo ($selected == '1' ? 'checked' : null); ?>>Bluetooth
<input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="2" <?php echo ($selected == '2' ? 'checked' : null); ?>>Radio
<?php } ?>